# How can i create a graph on network x with my followers on twitter?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to create a graph on python using networkx. i want to create a direct graph with all my followers and me on the nodes and having an edge between A and B if A follows B.
I store my followers on an array named result but im not really sure on how to create this graph.
Below is the code where i download my followers

```
twitter_accounts = ["AccountA", "AccountB"]
res = {}
#res1 = {}
follower = []
pbar = tqdm_notebook(total=len(twitter_accounts))

for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
    inner_structure = []
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.followers, screen_name=twitter_account,
                              skip_status=True, include_user_entities=False).items(10):
        val = page._json
        inner_dict = {}
        inner_dict["name"] = val["name"] 
        inner_dict["screen_name"] = val["screen_name"]
        if inner_dict not in inner_structure:
            inner_structure.append(inner_dict)

    res[twitter_account] = inner_structure
```

This is the get following part

```
following = []
for twitter_account in twitter_accounts:
    user_ids = []
    inner_structure = []
    for page in tweepy.Cursor(api.friends, screen_name=twitter_account, skip_status=True, include_user_entities=False).items(10): #5000
        val = page._json
        inner_dict = {}
        inner_dict["name"] = val["name"]
        inner_dict["screen_name"] = val["screen_name"]

        if inner_dict not in inner_structure:
            inner_structure.append(inner_dict)
        #except:
        #    print("RateLimitError...waiting 15 minutes to continue")
        #    time.sleep(60 * 15)
        #    continue
        #break
    res1[twitter_account] = inner_structure
    pbar.update(1)    
pbar.close()
```

Below is a picture of the graph i get which is not really what i need[image]

Answer (score 1):

If your only information on links/who follows whom is that everyone on your list follows you - then your graph will be "star-shaped", which may not be that interesting..

The information you need in the basic [NetworkX tutorial](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#creating-a-graph):

```py
import networkx as nx

graph = nx.Graph()

for twitter_account in twitter_accounts: 
    graph.add_node(twitter_account)

    for follower in res[twitter_account]:
        graph.add_node(follower['name'])
        graph.add_edge(follower['name'], twitter_account)
```

If you want a directed graph, you should use [nx.DiGraph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/tutorial.html#directed-graphs) instead of graph.

Edit: 
If you have an additional structure `res1` in the same format, you can just continue adding nodes and edges to `graph` (can add the same ones multiple times - this will have no effect):

```py
for account, followers in res1.items(): 
    graph.add_node(account) # make sure that's a node
    for follower in followers:
        graph.add_node(follower)
        graph.add_edge(follower, account)
```

Hope this solves it.

Comment: The graph its not really what i needed. I dont need just the people who follow AccountA and AccountB. I need there to be an edge even between the followers of the two accounts if they follow each other

Comment: I mean if AccountA is followed by B and C and B and C also follow each other i need an edge even between B and C @yuri

Comment: In this case sounds that you need to issue a tweepy.Cursor request for each of the linked accounts. In the above code you posted you only get information of  neighbors of the two twitter accounts - not on relations among them (do you have access to this information at all? )

Comment: i do have a part in the code where i download all the following of the 2 accounts the same way as i do with the followers and storing them into another array called res1. @yuri

Comment: I download from the 2 accounts the followers and the following and store them into 2 arrays. res and res1

Comment: but i dont really know how to use them together into making a graph with this information having an edge on two nodes if they follow each-other @yuri

Comment: will modify my answer later in the day unless someone does it before..

Comment: do you need the code part where i download my followings from the 2 accounts? @yuri

Comment: Just did - see if that makes sense

Comment: should i add that to my code or replace the previous one? @yuri

Comment: OK I cannot access chat behind proxy.. you should add this code to the previous one (naturally this gives you the superset of these nodes and edges). Note that this all could be done in a more simple and general way using a queue and a "max_depth" variable, this actually is a "breadth-first" traversal of the network starting from a given account.

Comment: Im sorry im kinda new in the stack overflow account thing so maybe i did smth wrong with the chat and you cant access… Anyway im going to post here the part when i download the following too just in case so if you can tell me if its ok or not to proceed with your code based on what i used

Comment: sorry i forgot to tag you @yuri

Comment: I tried the code you wrote but the result wasnt what i needed. Im gonna post here a picture of the graph i get if it helps you but it didnt change much from the first one  @yuri